# Does a team lose a review if the review was inconclusive?

Tags: rules, cricket, video-review

Let's say for example that the bowler delivers the ball, there is a very faint edge from the batter and the catch is very close the the ground. The standing umpire gives the decision not out, as they believe the batter did not hit the ball. The fielding team disagrees and calls for a review.

The technology determines that the batter did indeed hit the ball and the decision comes down to the catch. However, for whatever reason, say obscured camera angles, the third umpire is unable to determine whether a fair catch has been made or not, and therefore would presumably tell the on-field umpire to stick with their original decision.

Does the fielding team lose their review as the third umpire is unable to make an informed decision?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### It will count towards the innings limit of reviews for that team.

For example, the ICC test match playing conditions state in paragraph 3.6.5,

> ... A  Player Review  categorised  as ‘Unsuccessful’ shall not be  reinstated if, despite any technical failures, the correct  decision could still have been made  using  the  other available  technology.  Similarly, a Player Review categorised as ‘Unsuccessful’ shall not be reinstated where the technology worked as intended, but the evidence gleaned from its use was inconclusive.

ODI and T20I playing conditions would be presumed to have the same provision.

Comment: Just a point - after following up on the rules, this rule is now 3.6.8 in the [latest 2021-23 Test Championship playing conditions](https://resources.pulse.icc-cricket.com/ICC/document/2021/07/27/47d0a226-49c1-4c74-a77c-92889ce402d2/ICC-Playing-Conditions-ICC-World-Test-Championship-2021-2023-July-2021.pdf)